# How to redirect my page url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have made it so I can access my websites pages via shortened links, for example

```
http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=home
```

as

```
http://localhost:8888/home
```

But how do I make it so when I log in I display `/home` and not the `index.php?page=home` as default? Could I do some kind of redirect in .htaccess? What are my options?

Below is my current htaccess file to access all site without the long URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=$0 [L]
```

Comment: Not clear. How is `log in` related with this rule? Your login handler should redirect to `/home` once user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but I give you an example of how I do the thing.

If there is a session user cannot access sign.php by manually changing the URL. It immediately redirects to forbidden.php

sign.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: forbidden.php");
}?>
```

After redirecting, forbidden.php shows an error message and redirects it to index.php after 5 seconds.

forbidden.php

```
<div class="container">
<h3>You are not authorised to access this page!</h3>
</div>
<?php header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" ); ?>
```

You can improvise on this code.